Android app not updating correctly on some users' deviced
When we released our latest android app update, although the version number is updating on the user's device, the UI and a new feature are not updating.
Most Android users are unaffected by this. The issue only seems to occur on about 30% of Android devices.
Some affected user's have had joy by clearing app cache & storage. Uninstalling, restarting their device and reinstalling our app, but not all users.
Has anyone else had any experiences like this and does anyone know of a resolution to the issue?
The app UI should update when the user updates their app either manually or automatically.

You missed important info in your question like how is your UI generated. So what frameworks do you use for building the app plain Java/Kotlin, Xamarin/MAUI, Cordova, Flutter or what else. Where is "the version number" visible to the user? I assume your app is published and updated via Google Play Store?

Our app is built using Ionic Angular Capacitor. The version number is visible in Google Play app, and in the user's app About > Version section. The app is published on Google Play. The PWA and iOS versions are not seeing the same issue therefore the issue is an Android only issue.
